# Derivative of $f(x) = (x+x)$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

I'm trying to teach myself algebra and derivatives. I learned the derivative for $f(x) = x^2$ from a lesson, and now I thought I would see if I could figure out the derivative of $f(x) = x+x$ on my own.

I know the formula for derivatives is: $$\lim_{\delta\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+\delta) 
        - f(x)}{\delta}$$

So my attempt at algebra amounted to this: $$\frac{((x+x) + (\delta + \delta)) 
        - (x+x)}{\delta}$$

$$=\frac{\delta + \delta}{\delta}$$

Which doesn't seem right. (Isn't the derivative supposed to NOT contain the delta term?)

Comment: That's right, after you take the limit, you should have no more $\delta$'s in the expression. However, you have not yet taken a limit in the work you show above.

Comment: @wckronholm: I thought derivatives allow you to calculate slope without taking a limit?

Comment: NO! The derivative IS a limit. There are some short-cuts for computing derivatives which you'll learn at some point which will suppress the limit computations, but this doesn't mean that the derivative is no longer a limit.

Comment: Also, this particular computation might go smoother if you simplify $x+x=2x$ before you start computing the derivative.

Comment: Also, note that $f(x+\delta)$ where $f(x)=x+x$ should be $x+\delta + x+\delta$. It is equivalent to what you wrote, but maybe you just got lucky?

Comment: $\frac{\delta + \delta}{\delta}=\frac{2 \delta}{\delta}=2$.

Comment: @wckronholm: Aren't we supposed to let $\delta$ be more closely to zero. So, by this assuption, he couldn't take "1" for it as he did in his comment below? However this question was answered so completely.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the $\delta$s and simplify, you get $\displaystyle \frac{2\delta}{\delta} = 2$. The derivative is then $2$.

Comment: I thought about that, but if delta is 1, 1*1/1 = 1. Also, can the derivate really be 2? doesn't the slope of this function increase with x? And I know the derivative can't be 2 for x=0.

Comment: Part of the point of these exercises is to realize that $\frac{2\delta}{\delta}=2$ only if $\delta\neq 0$. This is where the limits come in.

Comment: Err... Isn't it a $+$ between the two $x$s? Then you get $x+x=2x$ which is a straight line, its derivative is constant.

Comment: yeah, its a +, but I though 2x is the same as saying x*x... Wait...DOH! haha yeah I see what you mean. And I also now see that it does graph a straight line. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Here is another great way to calculate the derivative of $f(x)=(x+x)$, instead of using the *Limit Definition*, which is the method you are using above.

The other way to do this is to use a combination of methods called the *Power Rule*, and *Sum Rule*.

Here is a mathematical representation of the *Sum Rule*:

$$(f + g)'(x) = f'(x) + g'(x)$$

This says $(f + g)$ prime, where prime means "the derivative of."
So this rule literally states: the derivative of $(f + g)(x)$ is equal to the derivative of $f$, plus the derivative of $g$.

In your example this would break down to:

$$f'(x)= (x+x)' = x' + x'$$

Now we will use the *Power Rule* to calculate the derivative of each individual piece (the $x's$ in this case).

The Power Rule states:

$$\frac{d}{dx} x^n = nx^{n-1} $$
Note: $\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx}$ means to take the derivative with respect to $x$. So this rule states that the derivative of $x^n$ is equal to multiplying $x$ by $n$,and then subtracting $1$ from the exponent.

Here is the Power rule applied to $x' + x'$:

Remember that $x$ is really $x^1$, so

$$\frac d{dx}(x^1) = 1\cdot x^{1-1} = x^0 = 1$$

Applying this rule to both $x's$ we end up with

$$1 + 1 = 2$$

Which is your same result. Hopefully this made sense you. If you get the hang of these rules they make calculating your derivatives super quick, and also provide you with a way to check your *Limit Definition* calculation. Good luck!!

Comment: The power rule comes from two things (well, more if you are taking the power not to be a positive integer): the product rule, and the calculation of $D_x(x)=1$.  When you are just starting calculus, using the power rule for this particular derivative is a bad thing. You are replacing "this is why it is true" with "here is a formula that gives the right answer, and which, in lieu of the calculation we have replaced, cannot be verified."  Yes, it is important to have formulas, but it is more important that everything is well grounded.

Comment: @Aaron: I agree.  I edited the answer directly above to be more explicit about when Chris was taking a derivative, so as not to confuse the person posing the question.  In particular: prior to editing, the answer above asserted: $x^1 = 1\cdot x^{1-1} = x^0 = 1$; essentially asserting that "$x = \frac d{dx}(x)$".

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I always learned, solve first, prove later. It made it more conformable when learning the formal "reasons why," after having already applied the formulas in practice. @amWhy: Thanks for the clarification

Comment: @Chris Camargo Well, I don't in general have a problem with learning how to calculate more complicated things before (or sometimes instead of) knowing exactly why things work.  To a certain extent I wouldn't mind if my students didn't calculate the derivative of $x^2$ from the definitions.  I just think that this one derivative (and the derivative of a constant) need to be done and understood before you move on to calculational tools.  Take everything else in calculus on faith, but leave me those two calculations.

Comment: @Chris: no problem.  I *knew* you knew what you were doing, and what you meant by what you wrote, but I didn't want the person posting the question to get confused.

Comment: Personally I am in the midst of the "solve first, learn later" and "why is that and why is this and ...". If the guy's trying to learn by himself, I think he's more on the "I'm trying to understand something" side rather than on the "solve first, learn later" side.

Comment: @Aaron A very wise insight

Comment: @Patrick Da Silva I agree with you. I just wanted to give Matt some insight to other possible ways of solving this problem.